# Multidimensional array logic

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm currently being bamboozled by a multidimensional array.

I know a good deal about programming and I was wondering about the logic pertaining to a question from one of quiz modules from cpp institute.

```
int* t[2] = { new int[2], new int[2] }; 

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)     
    t[i % 2][i / 2] = i;
std::cout << t[0][1] + t[1][0] << endl;
delete[] t[0];
delete[] t[1];
```

When the compiler gets to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)     
    t[i % 2][i / 2] = i;
```

I get a little lost, is t[int][int] manipulated every 'i' loop? I know what the answer is so I'm just looking for logic clarification to understand how multidimensional arrays are calculated in loops.

Comment: yes, for every `i` the expression `t[i % 2][i / 2] = i;` is evaluated. That's how `for` loop works. I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Side note: This isn't really a multi-dimensional array. It's really one 1 dimensional array of pointers to other 1 dimensional arrays. This may have performance implications because none of these three arrays are necessarily anywhere close to the others in memory and may result in poor cache usage.

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array. It is an array of arrays, i.e. jagged-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way of iterating through all the combinations that works because it's only a 2x2 array.

It basically has the same effect as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        t[i][j] = i + 2*j
    }
}
```

But instead of nesting, it's relying on the fact that you can generate the pairs `0, 0`, `0, 1`, `1, 0`, and `1, 1` by performing arithmetic operations on `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`:

```
i | i % 2 | i / 2
-----------------
0 |     0 |     0
1 |     1 |     0
2 |     0 |     1
3 |     1 |     1
```

Comment: This made more sense, however, the question itself asks for the output of the program. That answer is '3', would the questions parameters be referencing the output of i? I'm just not sure what the "output" is counted, whether it's the expression "t[0][1] + t[1][0]" after the arrays get iterated through or just how many times i itself was iterated through.

Comment: @William The question said you didn't understand the logic of looping over the contents of the array. Without knowing what CPP Institute is actually doing this code, my _guess_ would be that the "output" is what gets printed to standard out: the `t[0][1]  + t[1][0]` calculation which will, indeed, be `3`. The program is only doing a couple things: It's populating `t` with values, then reading values from `t`, performing a calculation with them, and printing the results to the console. I don't understand which part you need more clarification on.

Comment: I apologize if I'm not being particularly clear: When the array is processed through the loop and the output is displayed through std::cout, what value is being "counted" to produce 3? Is it the t[i][j] values? Is it from the 'i' value in the for loop? t[0][0] is i = 0, therefore t[1][0] + t[0][1] is i =1 + i = 2, or 1 + 2 = 3?

Comment: The value that's producing `3` is `t[0][1] + t[1][0]`. The value of `t[0][1]` is set during the loop, when `i` is `2`, because then `i % 2 == 0` and `i / 2 == 1`. So `t[0][1] == 2`. The value of `t[1][0]` is set during the loop when `i` is `1`, because then `i % 2 == 1` and `i / 2 == 0`. So `t[1][0] == 1`. Therefore `t[0][1] + t[1][0] == 2 + 1 == 3`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was definitely overthinking the process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a print statement if you like to see it for yourself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
  std::cout << i % 2 << ", " << i /2 << "\n";
  t[i % 2][i / 2] = i;
}
```

which prints:

```
0, 0
1, 0
0, 1
1, 1
```

That means that it goes through every single cell of your 2D array, in a zig-zag fashion, starting from the top left, finishing at the bottom left.